# Remove unordered list from a smarty variable

Tags: php, html, smarty

Do you know what is the best method of removing the first `<ul>` and the last `</ul >` form a smarty variable?

I currently have a variable that outputs a menu tag: `{$menu}` and a sub-menu but i just wan't the first and last unordered list tags removed without it removing the `<ul>` tags from the sub-menu output.

Look forward to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an modifier(and attach it with `register_modifier`), which strips the first and last ul-tag. To achieve this, you can use i.e. an regex.

```
function smarty_strip_ul($text) {
    return preg_replace('~(.*?)<ul[^>]*>(.*)</ul>~s', '$1$2', $text);
}
```

and

```
$smarty->register_modifier('strip_ul', 'smarty_strip_ul');
```

and in the tpl

```
{$menu|strip_ul}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not very easy to solve...

Wether put an unique id, div/span element arround your list and change it using string replacement with JQuery'ies with document.ready() function.

JQuery might also help you converting the content of your container into a dom-object and then use :first and :last selectors to access the elements you want to remove and use .remove() function.

Otherwise you have to rewrite it in the smarty core which could not be that adviseable except you know what you are doing and don't care to loose the possibility to easily update smarty without conflicts or rebuilding the feature.